# Why does puma not have a `before_fork` method like Unicorn?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fork, unicorn, puma

I'm new to working with Puma and have previously worked with Unicorn.

The Unicorn config has a `before_fork` and `after_fork` method that disconnects the connection and then restablishes it after the fork.

However, Puma doesn't have that. It only has `on_worker_boot` which is conceptually similar to the `after_fork` method.

Doesn't Puma utilize forking of worker processes as well? Doesn't it need to disconnect before forking like Unicorn?

Thanks!

### Example files

#### config/unicorn.rb

```
before_fork do |server, worker|
  # other settings
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
  end
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  # other settings
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end
end
```

#### config/puma.rb

```
on_worker_boot do
  # Worker specific setup for Rails 4.1+
  # See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#on-worker-boot
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, it now has this feature: https://github.com/puma/puma/pull/754